# Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page. Magento 1.9.3.8

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

Ok, I have had this problem before and was able to fix it but now nothing is working for me for some reason.

I changed the web/secure/use_in_adminhtml value from 0 to 1 within the magento configuration the last time I was logged into the admin panel.  I was doing this to test secure connection on my dev site.

Problem: Can't login to my admin account now.  I keep getting the message "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page."

I have already tried:

1.)Update the core_config_data table and changed the value from 1 to 0 for path web/secure/use_in_adminhtml

2.) DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_domain' and
    DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_path'

3.) Deleted var/cache folder (There was nothing in the folder)

4.) There was no var/session folder to delete

5.) Checked my app/etc/local.xml files and added these 2 lines:

`<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>`

`<session_save_path><![CDATA[/tmp/session]]></session_save_path>`

6.) Cleared Chrome's cookies and cache, tried different browsers.

7.) Even though I have set the value for "web/secure/use_in_adminhtml" to 0, it still goes to an https page when typing in my admin address.  If I remove the "s" and leave it as http it directs back to the https address.

Any other things to try? I'm totally lost.

Comment: Update:  I've been through 2 pages of Google results and no "Solutions" have worked for me.  Any other ideas out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I figure it out myself.  I removed all entries in core_config_data table.
`SELECt * from core_config_data
WHERE path LIKE 'web/unsecure%'`

I added the values below in to the core_config_data table. I am now able to login to my admin panel.

[image: Added these values]